# Shell Sort Increments

Tags: java, sorting

So I have a project due where we have to construct our own Shell Sort using the given increments below. After some research reading up on the different increments to use, I have two questions that I hope some more seasoned programmers could answer.

Instructions from our Lab to implement the sort with these increments:

```
1, 4, 13, 40, 121, 364, 1093, 3280, 9841, 29524 (Knuth’s sequence)
1, 5, 17, 53, 149, 373, 1123, 3371, 10111, 30341
1, 10, 30, 60, 120, 360, 1080, 3240, 9720, 29160
One or more sets of increments of your choice.
```

My question is, have you seen in your experience the 2 below Knuth's sequence ever used before? In all the research I came across I did not see these increments and wanted to see if these were widely used. Not looking for help on these, just a better understanding. Secondly, wanted to see if you would have any suggestions to use on the "your choice" that would an interesting choice to explain to my professor.

Thanks for the insight.

Comment: They are likely made up, so you can see the effect of different sequences on the sort algorithm.

Comment: Wikipedia says "Shellsort is now rarely used in serious applications".  Given that, I doubt that _any_ sequence is widely used.  :)